# How to make image responsive in horizontal direction while setting a max-height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using the bootstrap responsive image class to resize my images. When they are displayed on a large screen the images become to big and are too large for the page. I want to keep them on one page no matter what.

I tried setting only the max-height by doing:

```
.img-responsive {
    max-height: 250px;
}
```

but when I do this the width does not rescale either and the images just stay small.

Is there a way to give the image a fixed maximum height with an ability to rescale the width?  So that when the screen gets larger, the images get wider, but the height never goes past the maximum height.

Hope someone can help me out!

Comment: You could possibly try adding another div around each image and setting a max height on that container with overflow:hidden on it too. Might work but haven't tried it.

Comment: @BillyMoat that does not work. The images stay in the fixed container, but they are cut off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use `background-size: cover`

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Edit: Think I may have misunderstood. If you want the image to be 100% width and scale height you can do this:

```
width: 100%;
height: auto;
```

Comment: How do I use this to set a max-height?

Comment: You could always add a max-height to the css to contain it below a certain height. 

Can you make a jsfiddle so I can see the problem clearer?

Comment: You solved the problem already ;-) I will accept tomorrow since I cannot do it yet, have to go now. Thanks a lot!